# R Subset XTS weekdays

Tags: r, xts

How do I subset an xts object to only include weekdays (Mon-Fri, with Saturday and Sunday excluded)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's what I'd do:

```
library(xts)
data(sample_matrix)
sample.xts <- as.xts(sample_matrix, descr='my new xts object')
x <-  sample.xts['2007']  
x[!weekdays(index(x)) %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday")]
```

---

**EDIT**: 
Joshua Ulrich in comments points out a better solution using `.indexwday()`, one of a family of built-in accessor functions for extracting pieces of the index of `xts` class objects. Also, like Dirk Eddelbuettel's solution, the following should be locale-independent:

```
x[.indexwday(x) %in% 1:5]
```

Comment: I show essentially the same answer, but relying on numeric weekdays which renders it independent of the locale used.

Comment: +1 Note there's the `.indexwday` function, so your last line could also be: `x[.indexwday(x) %in% 1:5]`.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks for pointing that out (and +1 chez vous). I wouldn't have appreciated the difference otherwise.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien: Well, I happened to have read the `help(weekdays)` page after `weekdays` annoyed me *again* by not giving numeric results.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Hiya. Has **xts** indexing changed so that this should now be `x[.indexwday(x) %in% 0:4]` ?

Comment: No, it hasn't changed. Though there is a bug (timezone isn't used in the conversion) in the xts version on CRAN.  That might be the cause of the issue in the proposed edit.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich OK. Thanks. It's 10AM on a Wednesday here on the west coast of the US, and doing `.indexwday(as.xts(Sys.Date()))` (on a Windows machine, running the CRAN version) returns a `2`, so it looked to me like that person was on to something... (Running [the example here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11871739/980833) also gets me wrong results, returning Tuesdays instead of Mondays.)

Answer (score 7):

By computing the day-of-the week given the date, and subsetting.  In the example, I use a `Date` type but the cast to `POSIXlt` works the same way for `POSIXct` intra-day timestamps.

```
> mydates <- Sys.Date() + 0:6
> mydates
[1] "2012-01-31" "2012-02-01" "2012-02-02" "2012-02-03" "2012-02-04" 
+   "2012-02-05" "2012-02-06"
> we <- sapply(mydates, function(d) { as.POSIXlt(d)$wday}) %in% c(0, 6)
> we
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
> mydates[ ! we ]
[1] "2012-01-31" "2012-02-01" "2012-02-02" "2012-02-03" "2012-02-06"
>
```

This really is not an `xts` question but basic date handling.