# Return data subset time frames within another timeframes?

Tags: r, time-series, subset, xts

There are very nifty ways of subsetting `xts` objects.  For example, one can get all the data for all years, months, days but being strictly between 9:30 AM and 4 PM by doing:

```
my_xts["T09:30/T16:00"]
```

Or you can get all the observations between two dates by doing:

```
my_xts["2012-01-01/2012-03-31"]
```

Or all the dates before/after a certain date by doing:

```
my_xts["/2011"]  # from start of data until end of 2011
my_xts["2011/"]  # from 2011 until the end of the data
```

How can I get all the data for only certain months for all years or only certain days for all months and years?  Do any other subsetting tricks exist?

Comment: Have you seen quantmod.com?  Specifically, the examples http://www.quantmod.com/examples/data/

Comment: Here is how to invert a subset, using `which.i`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32029644/841830

Comment: For one year `dt['2009',]`, filtering year and month `dt[':2009-01',]` and using a date range: `dt['2009-01-01::2009-02-01']`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use the `.index*` family of functions to get certain months or certain days of the month.  See `?index` for the full list of functions.  For example:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("SPY")
SPY[.indexmon(SPY)==0]   # January for all years (note zero-based indexing!)
SPY[.indexmday(SPY)==1]  # The first of every month
SPY[.indexwday(SPY)==1]  # All Mondays
```

Comment: Very nice. I never remember those.

Comment: I consider this to be especially mean by the package authors as they _hide_ these utility functions behind a dot.

Answer (score 15):

time-of-day subsetting is a little bit hidden, so I understand why it would spark a question like this.  The only other 'trick' I know is the `last` and `first` functions, which you can nest if you need to.  e.g. this will get the last 2 days of the first 3 weeks.

```
last(first(my_xts, "3 weeks"), "2 days")
```

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that there appears to be different behavior for `xts` subsetting of a yearmon date format for windows and ubuntu.

```
library(quantmod)
library(xts)

getSymbols("SPY", src="google", from = "2004-01-01")
x1 <- SPY['2006-01/2007-12']

x2 <- apply.monthly(x1,mean)
x2['2006-01/2007-12']

x3 <- as.xts(coredata(x2),order.by = as.yearmon(index(x2)))
x3['2006-01/2007-12']
```

The result for `x2` is consistent between windows and ubuntu, since the format is full date. However, the `x3` will produce different result for windows and ubuntu, after the conversion of the dates to yearmon.