# subset list of xts objects

Tags: r, list, subset, xts

There's a great post on here that has clear examples of subsetting an xts object: [Return data subset time frames within another timeframes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871572/subsetting-tricks-for-xts-in-r)

However, I have list of xts objects and I am looking to subset each component of this list by 
gathering all the observations from a specified date onward. So, something like this, but for each xts object in the list:

```
my_xts["2011/"]
```

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Can't you just use `lapply(xts_list, function(x) x["2011/"])`?

Comment: thank you! i hadn't thought about making a "function". this is a good solution, wish i could give you more points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lapply` to loop over all the elements in your list, and use an anonymous function to subset them.

```
lapply(xts_list, function(x) x["2011/"])
```