# get desired rows from matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, row

Say I have a matrix. There is a column showing the dates information, from first row "20080101" to the last row "20100101". The question is, how can I get rows from date "20080901" to "20091031"? It runs in R.

Example:

```
2008010106 a
2008010112 b
2008010118 f
2008010206 e
2008010200 w
2008010212 a
2008010218 b
2008010300 f
2008010406 e
2008010306 a
2008010312 b
2008010318 f
2008010400 r
2008010412 e
```

First column is dates( the last two digits represent hours in a day). Second column is all letters.

Now I want to get rows from " 2008010200" to "2008010412"

NOTICE that the dates are not in a sequential order.

Answer (score 2):

I like `xts` subsetting for this kind of thing.

```
library(xts)
m <- cbind(date=seq(20080101, 20080131, 1),
           matrix(runif(31*2), ncol=2)) 
x <- xts(m[, -1], as.Date(as.character(m[, 1]), '%Y%m%d')) 

x['20080110/20080120']

# 2008-01-10 0.4819532 0.9406910
# 2008-01-11 0.5447225 0.5776338
# 2008-01-12 0.5614482 0.4152551
# 2008-01-13 0.2356413 0.9192496
# 2008-01-14 0.9759123 0.8141157
# 2008-01-15 0.2912074 0.3847100
# 2008-01-16 0.2185788 0.6909651
# 2008-01-17 0.6544894 0.3287306
# 2008-01-18 0.1319076 0.6527686
# 2008-01-19 0.6391880 0.5336123
# 2008-01-20 0.6915097 0.4842339
```

The above example returns the rows of `x` that have dates falling between 10 January 2008 and 20 January 2008.

Comment: Would xts handle `'20080110':'20080120'` ?

Comment: @BondedDust - no, it won't accept that. See [`?subset.xts`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/xts/docs/.subset.xts) for details.

Comment: Ah. Probably because ":" is a common time delimiter.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Colons can be used when time is used in a subsetting operation (but as part of the definition of start/end points, not to denote a sequence, e.g. as mentioned in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11871572)).

Answer (score 0):

A logical expression that would evaluate the n-th column say the 10th can be used in "i" argument to `"["`.

```
n=10
shorterM <- M[ M[,n] >= "20080101" & M[,n] <= "20100101" , ]
```

This should work for either a matrix or a dataframe as long as these "dates" are actually character values with that format. The ">=","<=" abd "&" operators are all vectorized. This is "logical indexing". You do take a risk in posting questions with no code since most respondents think that is your job and may not test (as I have not). Next time post a small example, preferably with the `dput` function, and specify what the right answer is. Then you get tested code and everyone is happy and you get no close votes ... unless of course this is a duplicate which is certainly possible.

The offered example is used as a worked example:

```
> DD <- read.table(text="2008010106 a
+ 2008010112 b
+ 2008010118 f
+ 2008010206 e
+ 2008010200 w
+ 2008010212 a
+ 2008010218 b
+ 2008010300 f
+ 2008010406 e
+ 2008010306 a
+ 2008010312 b
+ 2008010318 f
+ 2008010400 r
+ 2008010412 e", colClasses="character")

> (shorterDD <- DD[ DD[,1] >= "2008010200" & DD[,1] <= "2008010412" , ])
           V1 V2
4  2008010206  e
5  2008010200  w
6  2008010212  a
7  2008010218  b
8  2008010300  f
9  2008010406  e
10 2008010306  a
11 2008010312  b
12 2008010318  f
13 2008010400  r
14 2008010412  e
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `between` which is a convenient function from `dplyr`. `m` from @jbaums' post

```
  library(dplyr) 
  m[between(m[,"date"], 20080110, 20080120),]
  #       date                      
  #[1,] 20080110 0.19957458 0.22814565
  #[2,] 20080111 0.44428667 0.24073101
  #[3,] 20080112 0.86218249 0.68175459
  #[4,] 20080113 0.31706619 0.48679117
  #[5,] 20080114 0.09629562 0.66931400
  #[6,] 20080115 0.81436380 0.35013160
  #[7,] 20080116 0.34077661 0.54417985
  #[8,] 20080117 0.71414292 0.52569811
  #[9,] 20080118 0.84745961 0.90069540
 #[10,] 20080119 0.04145519 0.05394461
 #[11,] 20080120 0.65274477 0.08029292
```